# Логика взаимодействия токенов `ERC20` с биржами

Tags: ethereum

Я не могу понять логику взаимодействия токенов `ERC20` с биржами. В спецификации токена есть функция `Transfer` здесь все понятно, данная функция отправляет токены от одного пользователя другому. Это как отправка эфира с одного кошелька другому.

---

Но если у меня токен реализован с начислением дивидендов то что будет если пользователь отправит токены на биржу? Внутри контракта на адрес кошелька бирже отправляться токены? И все дивиденды будут начисляться кошельке биржи? И для чего функции `approve`, `allowance`, `transferFrom`. Эти функции нужны для децентрализованных бирж?

---

То есть когда пользователь хочет продать токен через децентрализованную биржу то он надает ей права права пользования определенным количеством токенов и как только биржа продала токены то вызывается функция Трансферфром?

Как реализовать ERC20 токен так чтоб дивиденды пользователя всегда начислялись ему, только когда он реально продал свой токен на бирже - то они уже начислялись другому пользователю, который купил токены

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если пользователь перечислил токены на централизованную биржу, то чем это отличается от любой другой транзакции в сети? Ничем. А значит все дивиденды пойдут на кошелек биржи, тут ничего не сделать. И сложно что-то придумать.

Например вы придумали свой токен, ввели ему функцию `transferToExchange`. При вызове этой функции ваш смарт-контракт запомнит оригинальный адрес, будет начислять туда дивиденды. Но если вы продали свои токены на бирже, как теперь она может перечислить их другому пользователю, который купил ваши токены и поставил их на вывод? Получиться, что он так же не будет получать дивиденды. Снова тупик.

Функции `approve`/`transferFrom` придуманы для взаимодействия с другими смарт-контрактами, и в частности для децентрализованных бирж. В идеале пользователь видит код чужого смарт-контракта, убеждается в том, что с ним всё в порядке, и разрешает ему использовать некоторое количество токенов.

Пример использования `transferFrom` в `0x`. Вы создаете заявку на обмен одних токенов на другие на децентрализованной бирже которая работает по протоколу `0x`. Вы даете право смарт-контракту биржи тратить ваши токены. Как только появится другая заявка что бы удовлетворить вашу, то смарт-контракт потратит ваши токены, и перечислит другие.

Comment: Значит я правильно понял что реализация токена с дивидендами и возможностью продажи на биржи - невозможна или очень сложна. Но я все же не могу понять зачем мне функция TransferFrom когда у меня есть Transfer. Можете написать пример из жизни для чего нужна функция TransferFrom и approve и allowance. В Будущем как бы дописать до токена небольшую децентрализованой биржу-обменник (сторонний контракт) токена на ефир. Мне для такой реализация НУЖНО написать TransferFrom и approve, чтоб сторонний контракт-биржа могла взаимодействовать с токеном?

Comment: @VitaliMalinovski да, если вы создаете полноценный ERC-20 вы должны реализовать все функции. `approve` и `transferFrom` например используются в протоколе для децентрализованных бирж `0x`. Можете почитать детальней про этот протокол.

Comment: Так а зачем они? Пример навести можно в каких случаях они будут использоваться? Ведь у меня есть просто трансфер, зачем мне комуто надавать права на перевод токенов?

Comment: @VitaliMalinovski я добавил пример

Comment: Извиняюсь не заметил!

Comment: Если я правильно понял то получается следующее... У меня есть токен, я хочу реализовать у себя свой мини обменник токена на ефир, чтоб кто-то мог купить токен а кто-то продать после завершения продажи токенов. Когда ктото выставляет ордер на продажу, то он "разрешает" моему стороннему контракту, который я напишу, на управлением n-ым количеством токенов. И как только кто-то на обменнике захочет купить то количество токенов по той цене которую указал продавец, то обменник проверяет разрешение, и отправляет продавцу ефир, и вызывает ТрасфФром и отправляет покупателю токены, Правильно?

Comment: @VitaliMalinovski правильно

Comment: Но в стандарте ERC20 нету метода уменьшения разрешения, увеличения или отмены. Если я дам разрешения я уже не отменю, если кто-то использует разрешение то оно останется и он сможет опять использовать. Смотрю код на странице эфира. Я так понял самому дописать нужно те функции, которые в принципе должны были уже быть предоставлены. И для того чтоб у меня етерскан и кошельки видели как баланс так и общее  количество монет, нужно иметь TotalSypply и BalanceOf, а функцию Трансфер не обязательно?

Comment: @VitaliMalinovski для отмены разрешения вы можете вызвать `approve` с параметром 0. Повторный вызов переопределяет предыдущие. Я не знаю, как устроен етерскан. Если вы создаете ERC20 токен, вы должны реализовать все функции. Иначе это не будет ERC20. Етерскан например может смотреть на список функций контракта. Если он видит все функции от ERC20, то он отображает и общий баланс и балансы пользователей.